# Set different "to" address with PHPMailer for 2 different forms

Tags: php, forms

I have 2 same forms, let's say "form01" and "form02". When the form be submitted, one email will be send. I want to set 2 different email to these two forms, so 2 different people will receive an email notification. Can I do it in one "process.php"? I use PHPMailer.

```
<form name="form01" id="form01" action="process.php">
<form name="form02" id="form02" action="process.php">
```

In the "process.php":

```
<?php 

//Here I want to set 2 different "to" email address to 2 forms
//form01 ----> when submitted, send a email to person01 by "email01@domain.com"
//form02 ----> when submitted, send a email to person02 by "email02@mdoman.com"

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a hidden field in each form and check whether it was submitted or not!
HTML:

```
<form name="form01" id="form01" action="process.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted_form" value="form_01" />
</form>
...
<form name="form02" id="form02" action="process.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted_form" value="form_02" />
</form>
```

and PHP:

```
if ($_POST['submitted_form'] == 'form_01') {
    // was submitted form_01
}

if ($_POST['submitted_form'] == 'form_02') {
    // was submitted form_02
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are sending two email addresses, you don't need two forms. Here are two possible approaches:

### Approach 1

---

**HTML**

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email1">
    <input type="text" name="email2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**process.php**

```
require('wherever/this/lives/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// put whatever validation you want in here, and ultimately add the emails
if (isset($_POST['email1']))
    $mail->AddAddress($_POST['email1'], 'Person One');

if (isset($_POST['email2']))
    $mail->AddAddress($_POST['email2'], 'Person Two');

// Add the other PHPMailer settings you need, and then send
$mail->send();
```

### Approach 2

---

This approach allows users to type in multiple emails in a single field, similar to an email client like Outlook or Lotus Notes

**HTML**

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="emails">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**process.php**

```
require('wherever/this/lives/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// put whatever validation you want in here, and ultimately add the emails
if (isset($_POST['emails'])){

    $emailSeparator = ',';
    $emails = explode($emailSeparator, $_POST['emails']);

    $send = false;
    foreach($emails as $emailAddress){

       // ... assuming the email is valid, add it to the recipient list 
       // and set sent to true
       $mail->AddAddress($emailAddress);
       $send = true;

   }

   if ($send)
       $mail->send();

}
```